# takes a list of lists of numbers and displays them as strings in a grid

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-lists

I am trying to define a function that that takes a list of lists such as [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,4,9,16,25],[0,1,8,27,64,125]] and returns a grid of the numbers using "\t" like this

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   
0   1   4   9   16  25  
0   1   8   27  64  125
```

So far all I have is:

```
def print_table(alist):
    for i in alist:
        print(i)
```

which just prints each list out nicely... but still in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could do as follows:

```
l = [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,4,9,16,25],[0,1,8,27,64,125]]

print("\n".join("\t".join(map(str, v)) for v in l))
```

Which results in:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   4   9   16  25
0   1   8   27  64  125
```

If you want to reuse this code in a function, you can make simple lambda for it:

```
as_grid = lambda in_list: "\n".join("\t".join(map(str, v)) for v in l)

print(as_grid(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lists = [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,4,9,16,25],[0,1,8,27,64,125]]
y = []
for l in lists:
    l = [str(z) for z in l]
    y.append('\t'.join(l))
print '\n'.join(y)
```

This prints:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   4   9   16  25
0   1   8   27  64  125
```